# Create macro to replace double spaces with backslash

Tags: math-mode, spacing

When I set Mathematics tests, I have to follow the layout specified by my department head. This means that I have to have double spaces before and after variables and other symbols. I would like to create a macro which replaces a double space with a space then \ then another space (which will show the double spacing in the pdf). I am using TeXStudio. I do not want to write this in my LaTeX code, only in the Macro tab in TeXStudio. (Regular expressions??)

Comment: `\setlength{\mathsurround}{0.3em}`

Comment: @egreg: You should turn your comment into an answer, you can’t expect a novice to understand that without adequate explanations.

Answer (score 11):

TeX has a provision for this, which is called `\mathsurround`: normally this parameter is set to zero. Around every inline math formula, a space equal to `\mathsurround` will be added at either side (but it disappears at line breaks).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

If $x<y$, then $x$ is less than $y$.

\setlength{\mathsurround}{0.3em}

If $x<y$, then $x$ is less than $y$.

\end{document}
```

You should set the length in the preamble, of course, here it is set mid-document just for comparison.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the regular expression to do this in TeXStudio, after much searching and trial and error: (\s\s)+